# Avoid user calling function from console (express app)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How to avoid execute messages from console by user?

If we are looking here [example socket io chat](http://chat.socket.io/) and trying to execute message `socket.emit('message','text');` we will get *socket is not defined(…)*

How can I do this in my own chat? I'm using node.js,express,socket.io.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, that is not possible. The socket is client sided, and there is no way of keeping the user from accessing the socket manually.

Comment: If we are looking here http://chat.socket.io/ and trying to execute message 'socket.emit('message','text');' we will get socket is not defined(…)

Comment: Well, apart from the fact that you can't access it there - there is a real connection going and any whizkid can crack that open and send its own data. You could even connect using telnet to the service and spoof a browser. Also, try putting this in your console and figure out the rest; io.managers["http://chat.socket.io:80"]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was my socket variable in client.js was global.
I changed it from socket = io() to var socket = io();
)

Comment: Still people will be able to use the socket. Its not a waterproof solution.